# On windows 7, looking for Registry Key or non-gui command to Change "Use Default gateway on Remote network"

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, windows-registry

Does anyone know of the Registry Key that is used to turn on or off "Use Default gateway on Remote Network" ? I need to automate this change for many computers and want to avoid the GUI method of doing this ( see [`https://documentation.meraki.com/MX-Z/Client_VPN/Configuring_Split-tunnel_Client_VPN`](https://documentation.meraki.com/MX-Z/Client_VPN/Configuring_Split-tunnel_Client_VPN) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not stored in a registry key, it's stored in the RAS phone book.

The good news is, it's in a human-readable/editable file.

Head to `C:\Users\<UserName>\Application Data\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk`, and edit the `rasphone.pbk` in a text editor (like say, Notepad).

Find the section that's header matches the name of the VPN contention you'd like to modify, and then change `IpPrioritizeRemote=1` to `IpPrioritizeRemote=0` to disable using the remote gateway.

To actually edit it via a script, PowerShell is probably easiest.

To get you going, here's a PowerShell (v2+) command that will update all VPNs in the PBK to *NOT* use the remote gateway, and then re-save the file (run it from the folder that contains the PBK file you want to update, or add absolute paths).

```
(Get-Content .\rasphone.pbk) -replace 'IpPrioritizeRemote=1', 'IpPrioritizeRemote=0' | Set-Content .\rasphone.pbk
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell to enable/disable the "Use default gateway on remote network" option:

turn on:

```
Set-VpnConnection -Name "myVPN" -SplitTunneling $True
```

turn off:

```
Set-VpnConnection -Name "myVPN" -SplitTunneling $false
```

You adjust tweak this a bit so it will run on several machines supplied by you, or configure a startup-script that will enable/disable the setting at startup.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, but I think this Powershell Cmdlet is only available for Win 8 and Windows 2012 or later, [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554823%28v=wps.630%29.aspx)